# django: how middleware know something to execute before view is called and something after view is called

Tags: django

I am going through the django middle ware. I am not able to understand how does the middleware know somecode to be run before the view is called and some code to be run after the view is called.

the following image will show more clearly what i am asking

[image]

Comment: `get_response` is simply a function reference. This is the underlying middleware function, or eventually the view that will be called. In fact the middleware does *not* per se needs to run the underlying function. For example some middleware can decide to return a 405 HTTP response for example, and never run that function, or even run the underlying function *multiple* times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_response` is a reference to a function. That function is the underlying middleware, or for the deepest middleware eventually a function that will look to the URL patterns, extract the parameters and call the corresponding view.

Indeed, imagine that `f` is a function:

```
def f(request):
    return HttpResponse('foobar')
```

then we can "wrap" that function ino the middleware with:

```
wrapped_view = simple_middleware(f)
```

We thus pass it a reference to our very simple view. If we then invoke the wrapped view with:

```
wrapped_view(some_request)
```

Then Python will first execute the code before the `response = get_response(request)` line, then call the `get_response(request)` function, which will thus trigger `f`, and then it can process the response.

Django here thus for middleware implements a [*decorator pattern* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Middleware does *not* per se needs to run the underlying function, or it can even run it *multiple* times. We can for example implement middleware that will only call the underlying function if a certain cookie is set:

```
def my_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        if 'MY_COOKIE' in request.COOKIES:
            return get_response(request)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Cookie needs to be set!', status=400)
```

in that case it is thus conditional to call the underlying function.